# NSPredicate for location geo-fencing in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

Im very new with iOS/xCode development using Swift.  I'm attempting to do the following:

1) Store lat/lon coordinates along with other data fields (airport locations, i.e.: SFO, LAX, etc) in CoreData as Strings that are pulled from a JSON query (this task complete).

```
Entity Attributes and type:
apCode: String
apId: String
apLat: String
apLon: String
apName: String
apUpdate: Date
```

Sample coredata result:

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x7ff9db864bb0> (entity: Airports; id: 0xd000000000dc0000 <x-coredata://30BBE8C4-120C-4776-B565-618DA59AC7FA/Airports/p55> ; data: {
    apCode = SFO;
    apID = 6773;
    apLat = "-122.375";
    apLon = "37.618889";
    apName = "San Francisco International";
    apUpdate = "2015-03-19 09:59:23 +0000"; })
```

2) When user opens app, I want that airport specific info stored in CoreData to display after app determines their location is within or near that airport.

3) I am able to determine user's lat/lon using CoreLocation

My problem is, how do I use the NSPredicate to filter the fetch to just that one specific airport stored in CoreData?  I have tried the following:

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Airports")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "apLat <= %@ AND apLat >= %@ AND apLon <= %@ AND apLon >= %@", maxLat, minLat, maxLon, minLon)
```

This requires that I provide the following 4 values (maxLat, minLat, maxLon, minLon) upon obtaining the user's lat/lon. Not even sure how to offset the lat/lon to determine these max and min values - and even when using hard coded values, no results are returned - probably because I save the lat/lon coordinates as String (this is a whole other issue as I have a difficult time trying to save the lat/lon value from the JSON as a Double in CoreData)

The other sample I found online is the following, which I feel might be the right approach, but I just don't understand how to apply it in the NSPredicate:

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Airports")       
var radiusInKilometers:CGFloat = 1000
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "distanceToLocation:fromLocation:(location, %@) < %f", location, radiusInKilometers)!
```

This second approach I'de like to really figure out how to apply as it would be helpful to adjust the radiusInKilometers value to fine tune the user's location

Any help would surely be appreciated.
Octavious

I had a feeling that my approach to saving the JSON results for the lat/lon to Strings maybe causing the NSPredicate issue to apply the comparison.  As previously mentioned, I can't figure out how to save the lat/lon coordinates as a Double in CoreData.  Here is my JSON parse and save to CoreData code:

```
        let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary


       var items = [[String:AnyObject]()]
       var item:AnyObject

        for var i = 0; i < jsonResult[“jsonAirports"]!.count; i++ {

            items.append([String:AnyObject]())

            item = jsonResult[“jsonAirports"]![i] as NSDictionary 

            items[i]["AIRPORT"] = item["AIRPORT"] as? String

            items[i]["APCODE"] = item["APCODE"] as? String

            items[i]["APID"] = item["APID"] as? String

            items[i]["LAT"] = item["LAT"] as? String

            items[i]["LON"] = item["LON"] as? String

            items[i]["IMG"] = item["IMG"] as? String

            items[i]["UDATE"] = item["UDATE"] as? NSDate


            //Save to CoreData
            var addAirportItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Airports", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

            addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["AIRPORT"], forKey: "apName")                    

            addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["APCODE"], forKey: "apCode")

            addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["APID"], forKey: "apID")

            addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["LAT"], forKey: "apLat")

            addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["LON"], forKey: "apLon")

            addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["IMG"], forKey: "apImg")

            addAirportItem.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "apUpdate")

            context.save(nil)

        }
```

If I change the Attribute Type of apLat and apLon to Double, how do I change the above code to setValue as a Double?

Comment: 1. Save lat/lon as double. You obviously can't `<=` compare strings. 2. You can calculate max and min by taking the users coordinate and adding/removing a value x. x being the search "radius" (it's actually a square) in degrees. If the user is at 45,45 and you want to search in a 1 degree radius min is 44,44 and max is 46,46.

Comment: The final code snippet is out because `distanceToLocation:fromLocation:` is defined on `CKQuery`, which is part of CloudKit. It's not available in Core Data.

Comment: Thanks Matthias.  I had a feeling the storage of lat/lon as String was causing the NSPredicate comparison issue, so if I may, how do I format my setValue correctly to save those JSON values as Double in CoreData?  I have revised my original post with additional code snippet to include my JSON parse/CoreData storage.